# Reading Multiple bytes in Raspberry Pi over I2C using Wiring Pi library

Tags: pi-2, linux, i2c, wiringpi

0
down vote
favorite
I am trying to build one sensor interface using Raspberry Pi over I2C. I have installed WiringPi. I am seeing limitations of wiringPi library, that supports only 1 or 2 bytes I2C read. reading single or double bytes at each shot is lagging my sensor data acquisition speed. My requirement is to read 6 bytes at one shot. Could anyone please suggest how to achieve this?

I have tried to modify the WiringPi library and rebuild for my requirement, But when I am using modified function in my application I am seeing "Undefined reference error. Please someone help me on this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I removed your second question since 1) We prefer one at a time, 2) Saying you modified library source code and it didn't work then asking for help is like saying, "I am at sea, how do I get home?"  No one can tell you without more information.  But again: That is a separate question.

Comment: Since you could not accept this, your question has now been closed as *too broad*.  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works, and read ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to modify the wiringPi source code to read or write multiple bytes.

wiringPi provides a simple wrapper around a few I2C/SMBus commands.  If the commands are not sufficient you can use the underlying C read/write calls.

When you call `wiringPiI2CSetup` the return value is the standard Linux filehandle, say fd.

To write multiple bytes use `write(fd, buf, count)`.  To read multiple bytes use `read(fd, buf, count)`

See `man 2 read`, `man 2 write` for additional details.

Comment: While this obviously works, the recommended way to access an I²C host is through `ioctl(fd, I2C_RDWR, &i2c_transfer);` because you can do multiple transfers (e.g. register select, read) within one transaction with repeated start this way.

Comment: As per my understanding with this file pointer is it possible to write or read from the particular register address..? I don't think so..

Comment: @shivakumar Don't you?  Well I have done so and I wasn't dreaming.  There are thousands of examples on the www.  Perhaps check a few out?

Comment: @joan could you please elaborate with one example. I am beginner for I2C. whenever we setup a I2C it will return a standard file pointer. how we can use this file pointer to read register from particular address? 
Eg: I have tried one example like this below.
I2Csetup() returned a pointer , and its value is 0x04.
then i Written register address to i2c bus using write()
then I read it back using read() it was giving junk value. 
could you please explain me how it is or my understanding is correct?

Comment: @shivakumar http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_adxl345_c

Comment: does writing a buffer ensure that this `write` happens within a single transaction?